# C# .Net 3.5 Compact Framework: How can I read Resources files

Tags: c#, .net, icons

I use .NET CF 3.5. How can I read files (ico, bmp) from the Resource directory?
I tried using `Properties.Resources` but get an unknown method error.

Thank's for helping!

ps: I will be creating an application that uses different .dll files like, module.dll. I want to read the icon from module.dll to my controller ListView.

## Update

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myApp_CFG
{
    public partial class Start : Form
    {
        public Start()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Start_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image image = myApp_CFG.Properties.Resources.ico;

        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist in the namespace 'myApp_CFG' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Please post your code and the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
PROJECTNAME.Properties.Resources.IconName
```

Comment: This option is Not working! The properties is unknow. I tried like that and this.Properties.Resources.IconName but unknow command.